# Check values in two different columns and replace non-identical values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this df

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 4 |
| 111 | 4 |
| 112 | 0 |
| 112 | 2 |
| 113 | 3 |
| 113 | 3 |
| 114 | nan |
| 114 | 1 |

I want to replace nan and 0 values with other values from col B for the corresponding item from col A as follows:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 4 |
| 111 | 4 |
| 112 | 2 |
| 112 | 2 |
| 113 | 3 |
| 113 | 3 |
| 114 | 1 |
| 114 | 1 |

I tried this but this not returning the correct values

```
df['B'].fillna(0)
df=df.merge(df[B > 0].groupby('$LINK:NO').size().reset_index(name='B'), on='A')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace values less or equal `0` to missing values in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), so possible get first non missing values per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df['B'] = (df.assign(new = df['B'].where(df['B'].gt(0)))
             .groupby('A')['new']
             .transform('first'))
print (df)
     A    B
0  111  4.0
1  111  4.0
2  112  2.0
3  112  2.0
4  113  3.0
5  113  3.0
6  114  1.0
7  114  1.0
```

Another idea is sorting use `max`:

```
df['B'] = df.sort_values('B').groupby('A').transform('max')
print (df)
     A    B
0  111  4.0
1  111  4.0
2  112  2.0
3  112  2.0
4  113  3.0
5  113  3.0
6  114  1.0
7  114  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! there is a ) missing before groupby
df['B'] = df.assign(new = df['B'].where(df['B'].gt(0))).groupby('$LINK:NO')['new'].transform('first')